# How to get a Widget as a QListWidget with 2 columns (with some constraints)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Looking for : To display log messages, with date-time (grey color) and message (red for errors, orange for warnings ... -> number of colors not etablished and have to be flexible). Sometimes we will need to open a link from the message, the act to open not etablished  (context menu, simple click -> nevermind)

History : 1- I tried `QTextBrowser` with html text style -> after 500 lines, it begin to slow the app, after a lot, it crashes the app

2- I Tried `QListWidget` with only the message with color (not the date-time), works very well !

So now you understand that I need a second column, the date-time in grey color.

My Question is: what is the easiest, more efficient way to do it, by keeping the `QListWidget` style, that I like.

I heard about `QTreeWidget` and `QTableWidget` to do that, but what is the best and what properties whould I change for those widgets? (to sum up : 2 columns with 2 different text colors, the ability to open links, the `QListWidget` style, and scrolling bar always at bottom)

Windows, C++, Qt 5

Comment: I use a table widget for my log in my Qt applications.

Comment: `QTreeWidget` display items as a tree (like the left column of Windows Explorer). You should go with `QTableWidget`, but I don't think you will be able to display links without some code. Take a look at the Qt docs. It's the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

**MainWindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeWidget>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void contextMenuRequest(const QPoint& pos);
    void openLink();

private:
    QTreeWidget* treeWidget;
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QTime>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
    treeWidget->setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500);
    treeWidget->setColumnCount(2);
    treeWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    connect(treeWidget, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(contextMenuRequest(QPoint)));

    QStringList headers;
    headers << "Date" << "Message";

    treeWidget->setHeaderLabels(headers);

    QTreeWidgetItem* errorItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    errorItem->setForeground(1, QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)));
    errorItem->setText(0, QTime::currentTime().toString());
    errorItem->setText(1, "error message");

    QTreeWidgetItem* warningItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    warningItem->setForeground(1, QBrush(QColor(255, 165, 0)));
    warningItem->setText(0, QTime::currentTime().toString());
    warningItem->setText(1, "warning message");

    treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(errorItem);
    treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(warningItem);

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* item;
        if (i % 2)
        {
            item = errorItem->clone();
            treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
        }
        else
        {
            item = warningItem->clone();
            treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
        }
        treeWidget->scrollToItem(item); //call after adding new item
    }

    resize(500, 500);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::contextMenuRequest(const QPoint& pos)
{
    QAction* openAction = new QAction("Open link", this);
    connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openLink()));

    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction(openAction);

    menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}

void MainWindow::openLink()
{

}
```